# Adding $locationProvider to config causing error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

Im just learning angular, When i add $locationProvider to my .config, im getting the following error. Removing any reference to $locationProvider removes the error. Is this some angular version error, i have tried different (higher) versions? Im not sure how to add the $locationProvider in without getting the error. Any help would be appreciated.

Ive set up   in index.html

```
Error: Error: [$injector:modulerr]  http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.9/$injector/modulerr?p0=styleApp&p1=%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.9%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DstyleApp%0AF%2F%3C%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.9%2Fangular.min.js%3A6%3A449%0AVc%2Fb.
```

My config looks like:

```
styleApp.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        // route for the home page
        .when('#/', {
            templateUrl : '/page/page1.html',
            controller  : 'mainCtrl'
        })
        // route for 2nd page
        .when('#page2', {
            templateUrl : '/subdir/page2.html',

        })

        // route for the 3rdpage
        .when('#page3', {
            templateUrl : '/subdir/page3.html',

        })
        .when('#page4', {
            templateUrl : '/subdir/page4.html',

        })

        .when('#page5', {
            templateUrl : '/subdirn/page5.html',

        });

        // use the HTML5 History API
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add   'ngRoute', as a dependency to your module like this:

```
var styleApp = anular.module('moduleName', ['ngRoute']);
```

Secondly, html5Mode makes your URLs look like normal URLs, so you should remove the # from all the routes; consequently, the route for page 4 will look like this:

```
.when('/page4', {
        templateUrl : '/subdir/page4.html',
    })
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed the urls over. I had already added ngRoute, I should have mentioned that in my originaI question. Still getting the error message though

Comment: Add something like this in index.html with the location of ngRoute package <script src="location/angular-route.js"></script> or add to your bower.json "angular-route": "version",